# Unable to read files in directory even though ACL set

Tags: permissions, acl

I am having problems listing the contents of a directory `/var/log/httpd` by a user that has a secondary group membership of `dba` even though there is an ACL for it.  It used to work a while ago. (I'm sure you've heard *that* before.)

User: `oracle`

Groups:

```
[oracle] > groups
oinstall dba
```

When I try to list the contents of the directory `/var/log/httpd` or a file in that directory, I get

```
[oracle] > ls -o /var/log/httpd/access.log
ls: cannot access /var/log/httpd/access.log: Permission denied
[oracle] > ls -o /var/log/httpd/
ls: cannot open directory /var/log/httpd/: Permission denied
```

So I did a `getfacl` on the directory, and get this:

```
[oracle] > getfacl -p /var/log/httpd
# file: /var/log/httpd
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
group:dba:r-x                   #effective:---
mask::---
other::---
```

When I do a `getfacl` on a file in that directory, I get:

```
[oracle] > getfacl -p /var/log/httpd/access.log
getfacl: /var/log/httpd/access.log: Permission denied
```

Things I looked at:

Listing of `getfacl` command at each directory level:

```
[oracle] > ls -o /var/log/httpd/access.log
ls: cannot access /var/log/httpd/access.log: Permission denied
[oracle] > ls -o /var/log/httpd/
ls: cannot open directory /var/log/httpd/: Permission denied
[oracle] > ls  /var/log/httpd/
ls: cannot open directory /var/log/httpd/: Permission denied
[oracle] > ls  -d /var/log/httpd/
/var/log/httpd/
[oracle] > ls  -ld /var/log/httpd/
drwx------+ 2 root root 4096 Jun 21 03:19 /var/log/httpd/
```

Checked ACLs of each parent directory level:

```
[oracle] > getfacl -p /var/log
# file: /var/log
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

[oracle] > getfacl -p /var
# file: /var
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
```

Linux version info:

```
[oracle] > uname -a
Linux plxxxx01 4.14.35-1902.7.3.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Oct 31 10:06:41 PDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After reading the `man` page for `getfacl` I see information on effective permissions and masks, but I still am not sure why the effective permission is `#effective:---` for the `dba` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mask::---` is the problem. This value limits the permissions for named users and named groups. In other words: Whatever the setting of `group:dba:` is, the group never gets any permissions.

You can correct this with `setfacl -m m:rwx /var/log/httpd`

Comment: Thanks for the mask explanation/solution.  Finally remembered when it "used to work" -- on Solaris!